# VS C# How do you view data at design time?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

This is coming from a 15 year veteran of Delphi who has taken a State Job where Visual Studio 2010 C# is used.

So how do I see data at design time?  It seems to elude me. At least it does not seem possible on the surface.

TIA...

Comment: How to view data in the DataGridView at Design Time?

Comment: You want to see actual date from an Access database in a Windows Forms program without running the program? Why?

Comment: Are you using traditional datasets, EF, some homemade OLEDB?  There's not a way to see the <raw> data in the designer but VS has visualizers that you can use depending on your answer to my question.

Comment: please be more specific, add some sample code if available...

Comment: Why?  Rapid Application Development  !!!!!   In Delphi which IMHO is RAD by leaps and bounds has the ability to see data inside a grid at design time either via a Table component or a Query component and then the grid component columns are editable directly without going to an editor and clicking an ok button to see the results.  There is way too much trial and error with VS.

Comment: The question is can you or can you not see data at design time inside a datagridview?   It is really a slow process to right click to edit columns and make adjustments and run the program just to see the results.   Why can't Microsoft improve VS to make data viewable inside it's grids at design time and make the grids adjustable directly?

Comment: And if the program is huge and take a while to build..... It just isn't a Rapid Application Development mindset.  I hate to be so negative toward VS, but when you have worked 15 years with Filet Mignon ( Delphi ) and now have to work with something less than hamburger...it can be quite frustrating and irritating.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server Object Explorer or Server Explorer to view or modify database structure and data at design time.

Here is a [good article series](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2014/09/24/sql-server-object-explorer-10-days-of-ssdt-day-6.aspx) about SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) which in linked article trains working with SQL Server Object Explorer.